# PHP IIS and SQLSRV | Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: php, iis, sqlsrv

I know some versions of what I will ask have been asked before but nothing as specific as I need help with.

I setup a Server 2016 IIS Box, used Web Platform Installer 5.0 to deploy PHP 7.4 and Microsofts SQL Server Driver for that version (both x64). I then changed the identity of the app pool in IIS to a domain service account domain\svc-php

However, when trying to connect to a remote SQL Server I get the following error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Now I know how to assign access in SQL, my main issue is I want PHP to use the identity of the App Pool so I can use Windows Auth between App Server and SQL Server without having to use SQL Auth. On the User to App side, I want windows authentication on the server itself so I know who is logging in, this works, with Windows Auth enabled on IIS I can get

> $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] = domain\usersname

The only thing I have thought of is impersonate should be set one way or the other. I have tried both setting to 0 as well as not including and nether changes the settings in PHPInfo(), its always 1 although I dont think this matters.

```
fastcgi.impersonate = 0
```

So in a nutshell, I just want to force PHP to use the App Pool as the identity used to query SQL. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it did need to be set to:

> fastcgi.impersonate = 0

The reason it wasn't working before was it was referenced lower in the php.ini a second time so my edits to the higher one were being overwritten.

To be clear to help others....

- Windows Auth on IIS for Users works fine and is unrelated to PHP to SQL
- Using fastcgi.impersonate = 0 does seem to get SQLSrv driver to use the App Pool ID which is what I wanted

Comment: It is appreciated if you could accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Will do, still have 30 mins before I can